# Does ssh require internet on both parties?

Tags: ssh, networking

What I tried doing it turning off my laptop wifi, and then trying to ssh from my computer to my laptop. My computer does have internet.

I got the error message

```
ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: No route to host
```

So does this mean that both parties must have internet, or is there a way that I can ssh without internet? I ask become something I have problem with internet, but I would still like to connect to my laptop from my school. Is this possible if my laptop does not have internet?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "I would still like to connect to my laptop from my school"? When you attempt this connection, where will you and your laptop be relative to the school network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to a host that is outside your local network you will need internet, but for hosts that are in your local network, you need only `ssh user@hostname/ipaddress`. And make sure that ssh is installed on the system you are trying to connect to.

What you are trying to do is connect to a machine that is not available on any **network(Not internet)**. Your machine needs to be connected to a network in order for another machine to access it using `ssh`.